# Kivy Buildozer apk crash

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to build an app using kivy. As starter, i tried building a simple button app. When i try to open the app it crashes instantly without even opening and this is the logcat error message of the application.

> E/art     (20411):
>   dlopen("/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so",
>   RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so"
>   not found
>
> E/art     (20411):
>   dlopen("/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so",
>   RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_imaging.so"
>   not found

Comment: please post the `buildozer.spec` file content

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/axwxrd1kafih4pb/buildozer.spec?dl=0                   here is the file in this link @DipanshuJuneja

Comment: you have to include the libraries you are using in the `requirements` in your `buildozer.spec` file and looks like you haven't added them

Comment: Can u tell me what to add and where. I am kind of new and don't know what to do. @DipanshuJuneja

Comment: Look for `requirements` inside your buildozer.spec file and you will see in the comment above that line

Comment: @DipanshuJuneja , I did what u said and added sqlite3 but there occured a problem while creating the apk file now. Here's the screenshot https://www.dropbox.com/s/cm8k1sy2jf46oh3/Screenshot%20%282%29.png?dl=0 .Also, thank you for your responses. And can you please help me with this again.

Comment: Do one thing, start building again, run `buildozer android clean` , delete buildozer.spec file and then run again `buildozer init` and now modify the package/app name and add the requirements and do `buildozer android debug`. It says here missing cython, I never faced that so obviously you might have messed a little with your spec file